# Dynamic Form Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic, survey

Main goal: I would like to create a dynamic form-building tool that allows the user to select certain options that, when chosen, enable subsequent inputs to occur.

An example of what I am describing:

1. Text Entry: Put in a Chapter Name.

   - Choose to add question

     - Choose Question type (mult. choice, check box, etc.)
     - Type in question.
   - Choose to add new question. If so, repeat ques. steps.
2. Choose to add new Chapter. If so, repeat add ques. options.
3. Submit whole content from above, and export (with the ultimate goal of being parsed/prepared into format for use, as per these [guidelines](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16eu77sD42xNRFZ8vJ2thhRhJiVp_Og-d3y6OzbYN1Os/pub#h.6gy361zihp1d) (but that's for much later).

Example of what I have done so far: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuanb/aPFXL/)
Note: Example is incomplete. Stopped because I realize I am building a mess and assume there is an easier/better way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any assistance that can be offered - I hope I was clear!
Kuan

Caveat: I am relatively new to programming/etc. That said, I feel I have searched quite a bit and there appears to be not much in regards to this specifically (the difficulty being primarily the nested nature of the questions, within the chapters).

JS Fiddle code:

```
<title>Dynamically build FT survey</title>

<script language="javascript">

function addChap(name) {

    var element = document.createElement("li");
    element.innerHTML = name;

    var foo = document.getElementById("currentChapList");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);

    // Update drop down select lists
    updateSelect();
}

function delChap() {

    var foo = document.getElementById("currentChapList");
    var allChildNodes = foo.childNodes;
    var lastElem = allChildNodes.length - 1;

    foo.removeChild(allChildNodes[lastElem]);

    // Update drop down select lists
    updateSelect();

}

function updateSelect() {

    // First delete everything in the Chapter selection list
    var currentChaps = document.getElementById("chapOptions");
    var newFoo = document.getElementById("currentChapList");

    for (i = 0; i < currentChaps.children.length; i++) { 
        currentChaps.remove(currentChaps.children[i]);
    }

    // Then re-add the remaining components from Chapter list
    for (i = 0; i < newFoo.children.length; i++) { 
        nfCont = newFoo.children[i].innerHTML;
        nfElem = document.createElement("option");
        nfElem.innerHTML = nfCont;
        currentChaps.appendChild(nfElem);
    }
}

function addAns() { 

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    var foo = document.getElementById("lastAns");

    foo.appendChild(element);

}

function addQues() {
    var allQues = document.getElementById("questionSubSect");
    var newQues = document.createElement("div");
    newQues.innerHTML = allQues.innerHTML;

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    allQues.appendChild(newQues);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<b>Current Chapter Index</b>
<br>
<ol id="currentChapList">
</ol>
<input type="text" style="width:400px" value="Enter Chapter Name" id="newChapName"/><br>
<input type="button" value="Add Chapter" onclick="addChap(newChapName.value)"/>
<input type="button" value="Delete Last Chapter" onclick="delChap()"/>
<br>

<br>
<b>Dynamically add element in form.</b>
<br>
Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
<br>

<br>
<b>Chapter Builder</b>
<br>

<form>
Chapter Select:
<select id="chapOptions"></select>
<br>

<div id="questionSubSect">
<br>
Question ID:
<input type="text" style="width:400px" value="Enter Question"/>
<br>

Question:
<input type="text" style="width:400px" value="Enter Question"/>
<br>

Question Type:
<select name="element">
    <option value="text">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="text">Multiple Choice</option>
    <option value="text">Open Text</option>
    <option value="number">Open Number</option>
    <option value="text">Ordered List</option>
    <option value="image">Picture</option>
    <option value="text">True or False</option>
</select>
<br>

Other open answer option:
<select name="element">
    <option value="text">False</option>
    <option value="text">True</option>
</select>
<br>

<br>
<span id="lastAns"></span>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add Answer Option" onclick="addAns()"/>
<br>

<br>
</div>
<span id="lastQues"></span> 

<input type="button" value="Add New Question" onclick="addQues()"/>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: This seems like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since you're not trying to address a specific bug, but rather get advice on how to refactor your current approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Palpatim. I chose to place it here as the question rests more in the concept of creating forms that can be added to dynamically (as opposed to a single list being added to, which has been addressed already on Stack Overflow) rather than my specific problem (though both are pertinent).

Answer (score 0):

I have done some investigation about dynamic form. Here are some excellent open-source solutions. They usually do it in this way:

1. describe form structure as JSON in the backend.
2. then use one of the following libraries to render JSON to form in the frontend.

- [jsonform/jsonform](https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform/wiki)
- [React JSONSchema Form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) (React) ([demo](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/))

[image]